# Can tankless water heaters be mounted to the underside of joists in a crawlspace?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, crawlspace, tankless

My single-story 1100 sqft home (1 bathroom + laundry + kitchen) currently has a gas 40gal tank water heater.  We're looking to renovate and remove the tank water heater.  It would be replaced with either 1 electric tankless or 3 point-of-use heaters.

We have a crawlspace of varying heights (mostly 3', I can sit up straight while underneath).   Is it okay to install the tankless on the underside of the floor joists?

Temps rarely drop below 50F here in Calif, if that matters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110839/discussion-on-question-by-dabi-can-tankless-water-heaters-be-mounted-to-the-unde).